# bulk "fetch as google" by PHP

Tags: php, fetch

I update my website content daily, around 15 to 20 new pages.

From my webmaster account, I "Fetch as Google" for each page, long process..

Is there a way to automate it by PHP?

Can PHP "auto submit" my new pages for me (The New Links are in a MySql data) to "fetch as google"?

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrong to do that "by hand".

I will cite [another answer](http://moz.com/community/q/is-it-dangerous-to-use-fetch-as-google-too-much-in-webmaster-tools#reply_177097)

> I would say it is not a preferred way to alert Google when you have a
>   new page and it is pretty limited.  What is better, and frankly more
>   effective is to do things like:
>
> - add the page to your XML sitemap (make sure sitemap is submitted to    Google)
> - add the page to your RSS feeds (make sure your RSS is submitted to Google)
> - add a link to the page on your home page or other "important" page on your site
> - tweet about your new page
> - status update in FB about your new page
> - Google Plus your new page
> - Feature your new page in your email newsletter
>
> Obviously, depending on the page you may not be able to do all of
>   these, but normally, Google will pick up new pages in your sitemap.  I
>   find that G hits my sitemaps almost daily (your mileage may vary).
>
> I only use fetch if I am trying to diagnose a problem on a specific
>   page and even then, I may just fetch but not submit.  I have only
>   submitted when there was some major issue with a page that I could not
>   wait for Google to update as a part of its regular crawl of my site. 
>   As an example, we had a release go out with a new section and that
>   section was blocked by our robots.txt.  I went ahead and submitted the
>   robots.txt to encourage Google to update the page sooner so that our
>   new section would be :"live" to Google sooner as G does not hit our
>   robots.txt as often.  Otherwise for 99.5% of my other pages on sites,
>   the options above work well.
>
> The other thing is that you get very few fetches a month, so you are
>   still very limited in what you can do.  Your sitemaps can include
>   thousands of pages each.  Google fetch is limited, so another reason I
>   reserve it for my time sensitive emergencies.

Comment: You have a point, but then again, I see online that there is a way, by using PHP, and I am still looking for such a AutoMated Way. Thanks Deele